# Jython pdb using interactiveConsole

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, pdb

I have a textfield in java which which I can type a python script to be executed. The problem is that even though I can import pdb and use pdb.set_trace(), the l(ist) command doesn't work (just displays EOF) as well as the breakpoint linenumber (just reports end of file). Here is a sample of

```
PySystemState.initialize(preProperties,postProperties);     
interactiveConsole = new InteractiveConsole();
interactiveConsole.exec(myString);
```

Does it only work with files and if so how does it work? Do i just need to use interactiveConsole.execfile()?

Thank you

Comment: I would love to try this, but I would need a little more than what you provided.